# Limit density of circle packing in a circle

Tags: packing-problem

The circle packing in a circle can be found in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle
http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html

As the number of little circles (packing 1 big circle) goes to inf, how to prove that the density (area of little circles/area of big circle) goes to 1?

This is not trivial without proving it because any of the gaps between the little circles will be multiplied by a number proportional to the number of the little circles, which is a huge number.

Comment: The density will approach $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing